# Multiple dispatch in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to make multiple request in componentdidmount right now this is what i am doing,

```
componentDidMount() {
   const {
     getVehicleGroup,
     getDrivers,
     getFuelTypes,
     getUnassignedDevices,
     getCarMake
   } = this.props;
   getVehicleGroup();
   getDrivers();
   getFuelTypes();
   getUnassignedDevices();
   getCarMake();
}
```

and saga is attached with all these actions. Now i want to run another function but only when these requests. This is something i am looking for

```
Promise.all([getVehicleGroup, getDrivers, getFuelTypes, getUnassignedDevices, getCarMake])
 .then(anotherFunction)
```

Here is my mapDispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 getVehicleGroup: () => dispatch(vehicleGroupRequest()),
 getDrivers: () => dispatch(driverRequest()),
 getFuelTypes: () => dispatch(fuelTypeRequest()),
 getCarMake: () => dispatch(carMakeRequest()),
 getUnassignedDevices: () => dispatch(unassignedDevicesRequest()),
 updateCurrentDriver: () => dispatch(change('addVehicleForm', 'FK_driver_id', [])),
 onSubmitForm: () => dispatch(addVehicleRequest())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I mostly use redux thunk, I think it should be similar in your case.
Try to do the following in your mapDispatch function:

```
 getVehicleGroup: () => async dispatch(vehicleGroupRequest())
```

Async functions wrap as promises and behave mostly the same, allowing you to do something like:
`Promise.All([]).then(nextAction)`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the two most "neat" ways are:

- with pure sagas: you dispatch one more action to start a saga that `take` all the actions you want to wait before starting the `anotherFunction` (but, depending on what you want to do with `anotherFunction` it could be useless)
- you can use [redux-saga-thunk](https://github.com/diegohaz/redux-saga-thunk) to get a promise from every saga you are starting and gain all the advantages of `redux-thunk`. I haven't used it directly but I'll do as soon as I need to do something similar

Comment: Actually what i am doing is loading the form, it has multiple dropdowns like Vehicle group, fuel types etc, i want to know that the form is fully loaded and all dropdowns are populated, because i want to use the same form for edit and i only want to get the record only if form is completed loaded.

Comment: Ok so my first solution could match your goal or you could use or, alternatively, you could use `mergeProps` (the third Redux's `connect` parameter) to add one more prop to your component once all the loaded lists are ready.
Prepare me a running Github repo and I'll take a look